# combine two javascript methods together

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

**SaveData.js**

```
function queryDB(callback) {

    var sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM DEMO";
    db.transaction(
            function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql(sqlTxt, [],
                        function(tx, results) {
                            var item_Codes = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                                item_Codes.push({item_code: results.rows.item(i).itemCode});
                            }
                            callback(item_Codes);
                        })
                        , errorCB;
            });
    return false;
}
```

**main.js**

```
 queryDB();
    console.log( item_Codes);
```

I have above two methods to retrieve data from database .It works fine but i need to combine these two methods to one method and return the  itemCodes array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var processResult = function(items)
{
  //process returned array 'items'
} 

function queryDB(callback) {

    var sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM DEMO";
    db.transaction(
            function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql(sqlTxt, [], 
    function (tx, results) {
      var item_Codes = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        item_Codes.push({item_code: results.rows.item(i).itemCode});
      }
      callback(item_Codes);
    })
, errorCB);
            });
    return false;
}
```

and call it with:

```
queryDB(processResult);
```

or you can use global variable `item_Codes` instead of function processResult

Comment: will it be a problem if i return item_Codes instead of return false;Then i can call query DB from anywhere and manipulate item_Codes

Comment: depends on how the function is used, it's your decision. but there might be a problem because the inner function can return result later and item_Codes  can not be initialized